# Transmit a password to inheritors

Tags: secret-sharing, passwords

I am looking for a safe and easy way for my inheritors to get a password after my death. That can be the password of a digital vault, a password manager, or anything else.

I could write the password in a testament but since a leak is still possible, I do not want this to be in clear.  I was thinking to encrypt the password in the testament and share right now with my inheritors the instructions to decrypt this password.

Does it make sense?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Assuming you're not a person of interest I think it would suffice to write something like "The password for my password vault is written on a note, which is hidden <INSERT PLACE>" in your testament.
Then it would require an adversary to first leak your testament and then physically find the note.
As with all security advise, you need to consider your threat model. Is this approach safe against a state actor, not at all, is it safe against average cyber criminals, highly likely.

Comment: A fireproof box is a good idea for this. Also have a backup webauthn key (e.g. Yubikey) in there, etc.

Comment: Bitwarden has an [emergency access](https://bitwarden.com/help/emergency-access/) feature. So does [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/features/emergency-access), not that I'd recommend them. Otherwise, it's probably best to use a bank safe deposit box or fireproof box at home as already suggested. A hardware key or an encrypted USB could be stored there.

Comment: Sometimes people entrust this information (or information to decrypt it) with an attorney, who will verify your demise before releasing the information.  It could also be entrusted to multiple people using a secret sharing scheme.